# How can I add an iAd banner programmatically to the top centre of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I have been wanting to properly fix an iAd to the top of my screen and I tried several solutions but to no avail. I need to fix the issue where you get a white rectangle in place of the iAd banner when disconnected and also it sometimes appears on the top and sometimes on the bottom. How can I make it always appear in the top centre, instead of going from top to bottom and bottom to top randomly?

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView!
    var bannerIsVisible : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
    }
    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    }
    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
    }
    func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ADBannerView` displaying on the bottom of your devices screen is created by `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a *no hassle* way of implementing iAd banners in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

You need to remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your `viewDidLoad`.